# User friendly semantic wiki?

Tags: wysiwyg, wiki, semantics, intranet, semantic-mediawiki

I have to develop for a small organisation an internal Knowledge Management platform,
enabling the staff to :

- get an overview of the organisation, roles, responsibilities ;
- share administrative and technical processes ;
- write and share articles (mainly about researches) ;
- share quickly practical information ;
- upload and share documents.

I was really interested in semantic wikis, because they can provide powerful linking between the different articles, writers, documents... and that way enable the workers to browse from a page to a related one smoothly.

However those people are not computer engineers and I am afraid that including semantic data in their articles wouldn't be possible. They need something user friendly and WYSIWYG if possible.

That way :

- do you know user-friendly semantic wikis ?
- do you know other tools that would enable this powerful browsing, linking automatically related contents ?

Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommand the use of the [Semantic_MediaWiki](http://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_MediaWiki) MediaWiki extention in combination with 
[Wiki Editor WYSIWYG Editor](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aWikiEditor).

You can embed the wikieditor (or basically any other WYSIWYG Mediawiki extention by using the following code:

```
! WYSIWYGField:
| {{{field|WYSIWYGField|input type=textarea|editor=wikieditor}}}
```